# Can't run custom javascript on the client with Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am new to React and Remix, never used it before, but I've done a lot of web development. I need to run some javascript on the client and nothing I've tried works.

In the old way of creating web apps, I would just put the following javascript in my html and it would all work fine. Basically, this just sets an interval, sends a response to the server and uses a third-party javascript library to render the data. Very simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // render the data with a third-party javascript function
    function load_data (div_id, data)
    {
        Highcharts.stockChart (div_id, data);
    }

    // get the data from the server
    async function get_data ()
    {
        const response = await fetch ('http://localhost:3000/getdata/x/y');
        const json_data = await response.json ();
        load_data ('div-id', json_data);
    }

    // do this every 5 minutes
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { setInterval (get_data, 300000); });

</script>
```

With Remix, I can get the library to load by adding a `<script>` tag in `root.tsx` like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

So I did a test to see if the library actually loaded. I ran the following code and it displayed the object I was expecting to see. So it seemed to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    {`console.log (Highcharts);`}
</script>
```

Then I added all the custom javascript that the app needs, so it looked like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    {`function load_data (div_id, data)
    {
        Highcharts.stockChart (div_id, data);
    }

    async function get_data ()
    {
        const response = await fetch ('http://localhost:3000/getdata/x/y');
        const json_data = await response.json ();
        load_data ('div-id', json_data);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { setInterval (get_data, 300000); });`}

</script>
```

That gave me lots of errors in the browser's console like `Text content did not match. Server: "async function get_charts ()` and several other errors, and now the javascript doesn't execute.

All the documentation for React talks about routing and components, which is fine, but how do you do simple things like just running some javascript on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically with React apps, you work with React components and not just raw JavaScript. However, if you want to use plain JS, then you can always use `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML>`:

```js
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
function load_data (div_id, data)
    {
        Highcharts.stockChart (div_id, data);
    }

    async function get_data ()
    {
        const response = await fetch ('http://localhost:3000/getdata/x/y');
        const json_data = await response.json ();
        load_data ('div-id', json_data);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { setInterval (get_data, 300000); });`}

`}} />
```

https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/

With Remix, you also have `app/entry.client.tsx` where you can add your client-side JS.

With that being said, if you want to fetch data, you should probably consider using the features that your library/framework exposes.

With Remix, you should look at loaders. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/data-loading